# 502 Bad Gateway Nginx FastCGI Cache

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, vps, php

I'm new to VPS and am trying to learn from mistakes. I'm got 502 Bad Gateway from a website.

This is my conf file from /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com.br : http://pastebin.com/N1gq3XHy

nginx.conf: http://pastebin.com/yNyUYg9Q

And this is my error log: http://pastebin.com/uSUxmACG

What is causing 502? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The "Bad Gateway" error usually occurs when nginx cannot proxy to your backend -- in your case php-fpm. Check to make sure php-fpm is running and listening on port 9000 (according to your config).

Comment: Thanks for the aswers! I did `sudo service php5-fpm start` and return this:

`start: Job is already running: php5-fpm`

@AlexeyTen php.ini: http://pastebin.com/ap60JzGA
php-fpm.conf: http://pastebin.com/pZrWzLjC

Comment: So, i removed the 502 error uncomment in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`    
  
`listen.owner = www-data  
listen.group = www-data  
listen.mode = 0660`

Comment: Check the "listen" setting in your ``/etc/php4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`` and make sure it says: ``listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`` -- by default some servers (like Debian/Ubuntu) set this to use a unix socket.